# CSS for table background and image in IE and Firefox

Tags: css

I am working on this site, http://store.springtoss.com/ 
The footer of the page looks fine in FF but when it's being viewed in IE, the category images does not overlap with the background image.

I have tried position relative and z-index as well but it doesn't work.

Any advice?
Thank you

Comment: Which version of IE? The pages look mostly the same to me in FF3.6 and IE8.

Comment: IE 7, the footer ran out from how it suppose to look like in FF :(

Comment: http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

Comment: this is a rush project, and I'm not very good with tableless design with many nested tables, thus created this using tables instead for now. If to change to tableless, it has to be another day.

Comment: @Sylph I agree with David, you better reconstruct the HTML to tableless layout.

Comment: Thanks all, I'm afraid it will take a while to reconstruct, I will give it a try after the site is being reviewed today. :) In the meantime if anyone has any suggestion how to fix this in tables, do appreciate your advice. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sylph: Viewing your source-code...

You're coding in a `Strict` DOCTYPE, so make sure all your elements are closed (`<img />`, `<br />`, etc.). Furthermore,

```
Ln 65: <table width="100"% >
```

should be

```
Ln 65: <table width="100%">
```

Then you also have a lot of lines like

```
<td width="150px">
```

They must be either

```
<td width="150">
```

or

```
<td style="width: 150px">
```

otherwise it's invalid code.

On `Ln 202` you have an unclosed `<tr>`. **Please fix those errors first**, run your code through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and then update your question for further `CSS` or other help.

Comment: Thanks stealthyninja! I will run through the validator and fix those errors first.

Comment: I have fix most of the issues except those that need to have alt for images , and though the validator states that some code starts with < tr> but all my tags do not have a space after <.